# How to move a svg element?

Tags: html, svg

Am new to web application development and I am actually trying to move a svg element and have some problems....here is the code for your reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <svg width=500 height=500>
              <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="black" />
              <g transform="translate(200,200)">
              <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:2">
                <animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                        attributeType="XML"
                        type="rotate"
                        from="0" to="360" dur="100s"/>
              </line>
            </svg>

</body>
</html>
```

Copy paste & try it,to get the clear context

And my requirement is I want to rotate the "line" along the circle,but I want it to rotate for my values(eg: I want to get line placed in a position that I want to palce it,but for my code it starts rotating automatically from begin to end position)...

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear.  It sounds like you are saying you don't want it to have a rotation animation.  You just want the line to be at a 45deg angle.  Is that right?

If that *is* what you want, then remove the `animateTransform` element, and just put a fixed transform on the line. Like follows:

```html
<svg width=500 height=500>
    <circle cx="200" cy="200" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="black" />
    <g transform="translate(200,200)">
        <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" style="stroke:rgb(255,255,255);stroke-width:2"
              transform="rotate(45)"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: You win  "interpret the question" Paul.

Comment: Mostly luck, I assure you ;)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an attempt at what i think you want:

```html
<svg width=500 height=500>
  <circle cx="100" cy="100" r="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="4" fill="black" />
  <g transform="translate(100 100)">
    <g>
      <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="100" y2="0" stroke="white" stroke-width="5" />
      <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" from="0" to="360" dur="100s" />
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Why do i need one more g element? 
If you inspect the element you will see that the animateTransform adds transform attribute to the `<g>` element so if you set a translate and use animateTransform it will over ride it.

If you want to animate a line around the circle you can use stroke properties:

```css
.circ {
  animation: rotate 3s infinite;
}
@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 500;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="300px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle class="circ" cx="50" cy="50" r="20" fill="black" stroke="red" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="70" />
</svg>
```

or if you want some thing to actually move on a path then:

```html
<svg width="500" height="350" viewBox="0 0 500 350">
  <path id="motionPath" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M202.4,58.3c-13.8,0.1-33.3,0.4-44.8,9.2
    c-14,10.7-26.2,29.2-31.9,45.6c-7.8,22.2-13.5,48-3.5,70.2c12.8,28.2,47.1,43.6,68.8,63.6c19.6,18.1,43.4,26.1,69.5,29.4
    c21.7,2.7,43.6,3.3,65.4,4.7c19.4,1.3,33.9-7.7,51.2-15.3c24.4-10.7,38.2-44,40.9-68.9c1.8-16.7,3.4-34.9-10.3-46.5
    c-9.5-8-22.6-8.1-33.2-14.1c-13.7-7.7-27.4-17.2-39.7-26.8c-5.4-4.2-10.4-8.8-15.8-12.9c-4.5-3.5-8.1-8.3-13.2-11
    c-6.2-3.3-14.3-5.4-20.9-8.2c-5-2.1-9.5-5.2-14.3-7.6c-6.5-3.3-12.1-7.4-19.3-8.9c-6-1.2-12.4-1.3-18.6-1.5
    C222.5,59,212.5,57.8,202.4,58.3" />

  <g id="shape">
    <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="10" fill="cornflowerblue" />
    <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="0" y2="-20" stroke="black" stroke-width="5" />
  </g>

  <animateMotion xlink:href="#shape" dur="3s" begin="0s" fill="freeze" repeatCount="indefinite" rotate="">
    <mpath xlink:href="#motionPath" />
  </animateMotion>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer....but I think you didn't get question ...Here is my clear explanation of my question 1)  I want the line to rotate inside the circle 2) Let us divide the circle from 0 to 360 degree ,and I want the line to be placed at an angle of my wish (i,e) is there any way so that if i give/hardcode 45 degree value so that the line is drawn at 45 degree(but in the above code the line moves without out controll).... hope now u have understand my question

Comment: @Aravind.A Does not the first code snippet answer your question? It shows how to animate the line inside the circle and i even explained why your translate did not work. etc. ? you can there hardcode the rotation of the line in the second g element etc.

Comment: @Persijn....Note:i am very new to web domain.  The second answer was a direct hit to my question.